# Why do I have multiple tracking branches on a remote git repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm about to perform an update of a fork I made a while back for a github project. When I tried to look at the remote repository, I saw this:

```
me@Bedrock:~/Downloads/git_proj/git_proj$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/jsmith/git_proj.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/jsmith/git_proj.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
     api-consistency               new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
     gp-1                          tracked
     gp-2                          new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
     master                        tracked
     refs/remotes/origin/new_conv_ops stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
     revert-6817-getfullargspec    new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
     tf-gp                         new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

I do not understand why multiple branches are shown as being tracked. Shouldn't I only be tracking the master branch?  If so, why is the gp-1 branch shown as being tracked? Does it just mean I *could* track this branch if I wanted to?

Am I correct in believing that my local master branch will push to/pull from the remote master branch, but that if I wanted, I could have other local branches push/pull from an arbitrary remote branch?

Comment: The tracked branches each have a corresponding local branch. You can see the local branches with `git branch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) on working with remotes explains your output well.  To repeat your output here:

```
HEAD branch: master
Remote branches:
   api-consistency               new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
   gp-1                          tracked
   gp-2                          new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
   master                        tracked
   refs/remotes/origin/new_conv_ops stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
   revert-6817-getfullargspec    new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
   tf-gp                         new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
```

Branches which are labelled as `tracked`, e.g. `gp-1`, are those branches which exist on the remote and which you have already pulled locally.  On the other hand, branches labelled as `new` mean that they exist on the remote but you do not yet have them locally.

Also, the HEAD branch being labelled as `master` means that `master` is the default branch for certain operations, such as `git pull`.  If you issue a `git pull` locally, but not explicitly specify a branch to be merged in, then `master` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are on branch `master`. All your push and pull will be done to `master`.
Delete the branches you don't want with:

```
git branch -d <branch name>
```

To delete them remotely, use:

```
git push origin --delete <branch name>
```

To change where any branch pushes/pulls from, use:

```
git branch --set-upstream <your_local_branch> <your_new_remote/branch_name>
```